# Passing templated reference-parameters to a thread

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++20

How could I make this working ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto thr = []<typename PrintType>( PrintType &p )
    {
        cout << p << endl;
    };
    string str = "hello world";
    jthread jt( thr, ref( str ) );
}
```

I don't even understand what's the issue here.

This is what clang 13 on Windows says:

```
In file included from test.cpp:2:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\thread:55:9: error: no matching function for call to 'invoke'
        _STD invoke(_STD move(_STD get<_Indices>(_Tup))...);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\yvals_core.h:1385:20: note: expanded from macro '_STD'
#define _STD       ::std::
                   ^
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\thread:62:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<(lambda at test.cpp:8:13), std::reference_wrapper<std::basic_string<char>>>, 0ULL, 1ULL>' requested here
        return &_Invoke<_Tuple, _Indices...>;
                ^
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\thread:302:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::thread::_Start<(lambda at test.cpp:8:13) &, std::reference_wrapper<std::basic_string<char>>>' requested here
            _Impl._Start(_STD forward<_Fn>(_Fx), _STD forward<_Args>(_Ax)...);
                  ^
test.cpp:13:10: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::jthread::jthread<(lambda at test.cpp:8:13) &, std::reference_wrapper<std::basic_string<char>>, 0>' requested here
        jthread jt( thr, ref( str ) );
                ^
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\type_traits:1482:19: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Callable = (lambda at test.cpp:8:13), _Ty1 = std::reference_wrapper<std::basic_string<char>>, _Types2 = <>]: no matching function for call to '_Call'
_CONSTEXPR17 auto invoke(_Callable&& _Obj, _Ty1&& _Arg1, _Types2&&... _Args2) noexcept(
                  ^
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include\type_traits:1476:19: note: candidate function template not viable: requires single argument '_Obj', but 2 arguments were provided
_CONSTEXPR17 auto invoke(_Callable&& _Obj) noexcept(noexcept(static_cast<_Callable&&>(_Obj)()))
                  ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: you can use `auto` in a lambda and avoid templates. `[](const auto &t){ cout << t << endl; };`

Comment: also, I would discourage you from passing something as a reference to a thread without ensuring its lifetime

Comment: let's start with the fact that you forgot to include a header for `cout`. And then, where do you think `jthread` would come from

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik: the thread is joined before the string is destructed.

Comment: You don't understand `error: use of undeclared identifier 'cout'`?  That error means nothing has been declared `cout` in your program.  There would be if you included `<iostream>`.  That header defines something named `std::cout`.

Comment: @BonitaMontero [this](https://godbolt.org/z/WGheEcWMG) compiles for me with some minor modifications.

Comment: @DrewDormann: That's solves an error I don't asked for.

Comment: @BonitaMontero I'm not sure what you mean by that.  Your question appears to be _"How could I make this working ?"_

Comment: @Carsten: This is just an example. I know that when I don't pass the parameter as a reference the whole thing works. But I need to pass the parameter as a reference.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik: jthread is from C++20: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread

Comment: @DrewDormann: "How could I make this working" - look at the errors.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a working example. However I'd suggest to use a capturing lambda instead (as SergeyA suggested in his answer)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is kinda unsolvable as long as we insist on passing `thr` lambda to `jthread` constructor. This snippet

```
auto thr = []<typename PrintType>( PrintType &p )
{
    cout << p << endl;
};
string str = "hello world";
jthread jt(thr, str);
```

is going to fail, because you can't bind non-const reference to a temporary resulting within `jthread` constructor (Note: `const PrintType& hp` would work, but I assume, it would not be what OP wants).

`std::ref` would work with non-templated lambda:

```
auto thr = [](std::string& p)
{
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
};

std::string str = "hello world";
std::thread jt( thr, std::ref(str) );
```

But it won't work with templated lambda (because`auto thr = [](auto& p)` will just try to bind non-const lvalue reference to temporary object of `reference_wrapper` type).

The only solution I can think of is to pass lambda with closures directly to thread constructor:

```
auto thr = []<class Type>(Type& p)
{
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
};
std::string str = "hello world";
std::thread jt([&str, &thr]() { thr(str); });
```

Comment: there is a solution (checkout the second snippet in my answer). And it assumes that *only* a wrapped reference is passed as an argument (which is almost always the case)

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik no, see my comment - your solution transforms non-const reference to const one, without any indication that this is permissible translation.

Comment: @SergeyA: No, it's not trying to print a reference_wrapper because the errors don't fit with that.

Comment: @BonitaMontero your errors are not about printing, they are about binding reference, as I explained in my answer. If you replace non-const l-value reference with a const one, you would see an error with printing.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a working example for explicit template instantiation that **works** with a wrapped reference

Answer (score 0):

TLDR:

```
    jthread jt(&decltype(thr)::operator()<std::string>, thr, ref(str));
```

---

The problem you are having is due to a substitution of `PrintType` by `std::reference_wrapper`, which is not recognised as a valid argument for `operator<<`. You expect the compiler to do an implicit conversion from `std::reference_wrapper` to `std::string&` when receiving it as an argument, but the compiler does not expect an `std::string&` there. It expects `std::reference_wrapper`.

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/thread: In instantiation of 'static std::thread std::jthread::_S_create(std::stop_source&, _Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = main()::<lambda(PrintType&)>&; _Args = {std::reference_wrapper<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >}]':
```

As you can see, you don't end up with `std::string&` as an argument, but with a wrapper: `std::reference_wrapper<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >`.

This code compiles:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto thr = [](const std::string &p)
    {
        cout << p << endl;
    };
    string str = "hello world";
    jthread jt(thr, ref( str ));
}
```

So, the logical solution would be to **force** the compiler to instantiate the template with the right type:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto thr = []<typename PrintType>(PrintType& p)
    {
        cout << p << endl;
    };
    string str = "hello world";

    // explicitly instantiating via a pointer to member function
    jthread jt(&decltype(thr)::operator()<std::string>, thr, ref(str));
}
```

Comment: Both your solutions used `const` reference, which presumably is not what OP wants. See my answer, it is unsolvable with non-const reference.

Comment: @SergeyA I assume that the author either gave an invalid example (that does not show the need for a reference) or doesn't know that there *should* be a const reference

Comment: While you **might** be correct, there is no indication that this assumption is warranted. Besides, your "solution" ties `thr` to classes which have `get` method on them, without any further constraint on the type, and likely is unusable in real life.

Comment: @SergeyA I updated my answer about my *assumption*.

Comment: @SergeyA in which real life do you pass an unwrapped reference for a function invokation within a thread?

Comment: Why not? As long as the reference is `const`, it is bindable directly. Overall, I do not agree with this approach at all.

Comment: @SergeyA anyway, the sole idea of my answer is about template resolution. And the second snippet just proofs the point